# SSAS Cube Filtering Data

Tags: ssas, ssas-2012

I've working on SSAS cube creation first time on real data(Although had little hands on experience on AdventureWorksDW08).I also have gone through the details for creating basics cube and all but have little question as to which are the pre-requisite for creating the SSAS cube **.e.g (SQL TABLE SHOULD NOT HAVE NULL VALUES) etc.**

I'm Tried so many times but it seems that data is not get refresh for certain result columns.